# Why to add both HTTPS & HTTP versions to Google Webmasters?

Tags: google-search-console

What are reasons, that we have to add 2 versions of same domain to Google 
Webmasters:

`http` and `https` ?

as they refer to same domain, we have extra headache to have 2 items instead of 1.

Why? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google treats HTTP and HTTPS as different sites because they are different URLs, and as such, they are capable of serving different content over each URL.

If you have no real need to retain the HTTP version of your site, then the sensible thing would be to redirect all traffic from the HTTP version to HTTPS.